# Umbraco Intermittent database exceptions during database operations

Tags: umbraco

I am using Umbraco version 7.4.3 assembly: 1.0.5948.18141

I am getting intermittent exceptions during fetch and query operations. I have scoured the web for answers and am coming up empty. This is what shows up in my umbraco log file when I get these errors. I have validated that with the same query that works over and over again, that occasionally I get this error. I have added retry logic with garbage collection in the exception handlers and sleep statements, but to no avail. Anything anyone could suggest to shed light on this would be extremely helpful. I am desperate. :)

> 2016-11-03 10:49:12,240 [P2872/D6/T1120] ERROR
>   Umbraco.Core.Persistence.UmbracoDatabase - Database exception occurred
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Database.d71.MoveNext() 
>   2016-11-03 10:49:13,442 [P2872/D6/T1120] ERROR
>   Umbraco.Core.Persistence.UmbracoDatabase - Database exception occurred
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Database.d__71.MoveNext() 2016-11-03
>   10:49:14,518 [P2872/D6/T1120] ERROR
>   Umbraco.Core.Persistence.UmbracoDatabase - Database exception occurred
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Database.d7`1.MoveNext()

Comment: And you expect anyone around here miraculously to tell you what went wrong with an obscure open source component based on just a few error message.

Comment: When you say fetch and query, do you mean normal fetch/query operations that are part of the CMS, e.g. list the content nodes in the content tree etc, or in some custom code in your views/controllers? please include more detail about exactly WHERE in the CMS these errors are occurring.

Comment: I am using the petapoco modules to access the database in my controllers thru my model classes.  I.E.                  oRet = Umbraco.Core.ApplicationContext.Current.DatabaseContext.Database.Fetch<SchoolDB>("SELECT * FROM _schools ORDER BY SchoolName;");

Comment: @rwilchek I'm running into the same issue. I'm using Umbraco 7.5.11. Were you ever been able to figured out what the issue was?